# Add git remote to atom

Tags: git, atom-editor

I have my app on local computer and on production server. I am able to push from command line. But I can't on Atom as I get no remote. I can commit but I'm unable to push or pull.

For some previous project I was able to do it, Atom was recognizing the git remote without me doing anything.

What is the reason? How can i add the git remote to Atom?

Comment: Are you using [git-plus](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus)?

Comment: Nope just the native one, no external packages. One thing I remember I noticed is that if I open the project on GitRacken then the remote is recognized on Atom too. I haven't installed GitRacken now but I guess there must be another way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check if the remote is set in the `.git/config` file. Usually you have something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://...
```

If you got no remote on the config file, add it with the following commands:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/nicoboni/italy-winemap.git
git push -u origin master
```

restart Atom and you should be able to push changes to remote

Comment: git remote is set, as I can push from terminal.. But I'm not sure what the '-u' in your command  is supposed to do..

Comment: `-u`  sets the upstream repo for future push and pull. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561295/what-does-git-push-u-mean

Comment: What's the point? The whole thing about Atom is it works with git without having the git binaries configured at the OS level. Out of the box they claim it is, but it LACKS Remote configuration. Therefore is incomplete. https://github.atom.io/